# Bubblesort visualization in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, bubble-sort, tkinter-canvas

I can't figure out how can I finish one simple program written in Python. Program basically generates array of ten random numbers and then sorts them using bubblesort algorithm. Whole shorting process should be shown on screen - such as this one

[image]

My current code is this:

```
import tkinter
import random
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(bg='white',width='800',height='400')
canvas.pack()

c = []
for i in range(0,10):
    c=c+[random.randrange(10)]
print(c)
print('Zoradenie...', c)

def sort(c):
    x=300
    for i in range(0,10):
        for j in range(0,len(c)-1-1):
            if c[j+1]<c[j]:
                c[j+1],c[j]=c[j],c[j+1]
                canvas.create_text(300,80,text=c[j],fill='Red')
            x+=25
            canvas.update()
            canvas.after(1000)
            print(c)              
    return c
sort(c)
```

But I can't figure out how to show numbers on screen. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why you do not look at the working code for an answer, nor your question.  You put numbers on the canvas with `canvas.create_text`.  The problem with your code is that you do not start by displaying all the numbers, do not display both after swapping, and do not use `x` to shift the display position.  The `canvas.after call is missing the function name, and should not be in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

To display the digits on the canvas, you must create a text item for each digit.  See the end of my code.  The harder part is moving the digits.  One way is to `delete` and recreate; the other is to `move`.  I choose the latter.

The hardest part, perhaps, is the time delays.  If one uses `mainloop`, one should use `after` rather than `time.sleep` (which blocks the looping) and not use for-loops for animation.  The problem is that the function (here `sort`) that naturally contains for-loops must be broken into pieces whose joint operation may be hard to understand.  If one is running just one function and does not care about user interaction (for instance, a pause button), one can use `time.sleep` and `update`.  I have done so here to make what is going on clearer.

```
from random import randrange
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white', width='800', height='400')
canvas.pack()

ndigits = 10
digits = [randrange(10) for _ in range(ndigits)]
tdelta1, tdelta2 = .8, .2
xstart = 300
xdelta = 25
y = 80

def color(i, swap):
    "Temporarily color digits i and i+i according to swap needed."
    x = xstart + xdelta * i
    dcolor = 'Red' if swap else 'green'
    canvas.itemconfigure(items[i], fill=dcolor)
    canvas.itemconfigure(items[i+1],fill=dcolor)
    canvas.update()
    sleep(tdelta1)
    canvas.itemconfigure(items[i], fill='Black')
    canvas.itemconfigure(items[i+1], fill='Black')
    canvas.update()
    sleep(tdelta2)

def swap(i):
    digits[i], digits[i+1] = digits[i+1], digits[i]
    canvas.move(items[i], xdelta, 0)
    canvas.move(items[i+1], -xdelta, 0)
    items[i], items[i+1] = items[i+1], items[i]


def bubsort():
    "Sort digits and animate."
    for stop in reversed(range(1, ndigits)):
        # stop = index of position whose entry will be determined.
        for i in range(stop):
            swap_needed = digits[i] > digits[i+1]
            color(i, swap_needed)
            if swap_needed:
                swap(i)
                color(i, False)

# Create display items and pause.
items = [canvas.create_text(xstart + xdelta*i, y, text=str(digit))
         for i, digit in enumerate(digits)]
canvas.update()
sleep(tdelta1)
```

bubsort()

This code makes it fairly easy to replace the text digit display with, for instance, a colored bar display. To develop this further, I would define a class of items combining int values and display items as attributes.  There would them be only one array of combined items.  With comparison methods defines, the array could be passed to any sort function.